# downloading binary data using R error

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I am downloading and working with some binary satellite.
I have about 1400 urls to download and process them latter in matrix format.

Here is my URL:
'nasanex.s3.amazonaws.com/AVHRR/GIMMS/FPAR3G/AVHRRBUVI01.1981auga.abf'

**Case 1:**
When I am downloading(through my browser) and processing (in Matlab) the file my matrix output seems to be correct.
[Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQF3i.png)

**Case 2:**
When I am downloading(through R) and processing (in Matlab) the file my matrix output seems to be incorrect.
[Incorrect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F1a1.png)

I was wondering is why is it happening this way.
I am sharing the 'R' which I have used for downloading:

```
download.file(myurl_1, destfile = myfile_1, mode ='w')
```

For reading the data I am using simple 'matlab' codes.

```
myfile = allfiles(1,1:end);
fid = fopen(char(myfile), 'r');
data = fread(fid,[2160,4320],'uint8',0,'ieee-be');
data(data == 250)= nan;
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `mode = 'wb'`

```
download.file(myurl_1, destfile = myfile_1, mode ='wb')
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it seems downloading the binary data requires
`mode = 'wb'`.

see [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) for details.